# How to hide always on fields on page layout

Tags: visualforce, lightning, page-layout, record-type

I need to hide some fields on a page layout . But these fields are marked with a blue dot and cant be removed .

I have multiple record types for the object and cant hide those fields at profile level .
Is there a way I can hide these fields for a particular record type page layout

Answer (score 0):

If they are the required field, then you cannot remove/hide it from the pagelayout.

If it is the custom required field then :-

1. uncheck the Required checkbox on the field on the object level and then open the page layout where you want to make it required and then double click on the field and check the Required checkbox
2. and where you dont need the field, you can hide it on pagelayout.

Comment: Thanks Priya ,,the problem is that they are standard and required  fields

Comment: @user75937, if you have any standard required picklist field then you can set a default value for the picklist field and then remove it from the pagelayout. I tried and it worked.

Comment: @user75937, you can hide the standard required field using dynamic layout on lightning record pages. refer this [dynamic forms](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) but the problem will be that user will not be save the required as it will be missing the required field.